# The await operator can only be used within an async method

Tags: c#, async-await

I have an interface `ISFactory` as follows.

```
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public interface IStreamFactory
    {
        Stream CreateSPStream(string sPName);
    }
}
```

On Windows non-universal version the above function was implemented as follows.

```
public Stream CreateSerialPortStream(string serialPortName)
{
    var p = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
    p.PortName = serialPortName;
    p.BaudRate = 9600;
    p.RtsEnable = true;
    p.DtrEnable = true;
    p.ReadTimeout = 150;
    p.Open();
    return p.BaseStream;
}
```

This implementation is no longer available in Windows Universal. What I attempted is shown below.

```
public  Stream CreateSerialPortStream(string serialPortName)
{
    var selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector(serialPortName); //Get the serial port on port '3'
    var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
    if (devices.Any()) //if the device is found
    {
        var deviceInfo = devices.First();
        var serialDevice = await SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
        //Set up serial device according to device specifications:
        //This might differ from device to device
        serialDevice.BaudRate = 19600;
        serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
        serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
    }
}
```

I get the following error.

> The await operator can only be used within an async method.`

Can anyone suggest a way around this.

Comment: `public async Task<Stream> CreateSerialPortStream(string serialPortName)`

Comment: @Nkosi - Can I get `Stream` from `Task<Stream>`. I am passing `stream` to other functions which is failing now.

Comment: @Nkosi - so I have to change the interface?

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. check `serialDevice.InputStream`

Comment: @Nkosi - But still I have to change the return type to Task<Stream> ?

Comment: Yes if you are doing `async/await` then you have to return a `Task`

Comment: @Nkosi - can't find serialDevice.InputStream

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.serialcommunication.serialdevice.inputstream.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Take a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34160376/windows-universal-app-serial-ports-wont-open-serialdevice-fromidasync-always-n

Answer (score 10):

The *best* approach is to make the method `async`, as the compiler error indicates:

```
public async Task<Stream> CreateSerialPortStreamAsync(string serialPortName)
```

This will require the interface to change as well:

```
Task<Stream> CreateSerialPortStreamAsync(string serialPortName);
```

And yes, all callers of this method will need to be updated.

Comment: What will I return from the function?

Comment: @liv2hak you just return a `Stream`, which is automatically wrapped in a `Task<Stream>`

Comment: @zerkms - When I add async to the interface function, it says modified async is not valid for this item.

Comment: @liv2hak `async` keyword is a part of the implementation, not the interface. Just go through the answer once again - it mentions that the signature of the method and of the interface change slightly differently.

Answer (score 2):

**1) (Preferable)** You can make your method *async* by changing its sugnature to :

```
public  async Task<Stream> CreateSerialPortStream(string serialPortName)
```

each method calling `CreateSerialPortStream` should be async too. (Also i suggest to rename your method to *CreateSerialPortStreamAsync*)

**2)** If you don't want to change your method signature for some reason, you can leave it as is, but use *Wait()*. In this case, you will lose  asynchronous calling.

```
public  Stream CreateSerialPortStream(string serialPortName)
{
    var selector = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector(serialPortName); //Get the serial port on port '3'
    var devicesTask = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
    devicesTask.Wait();
    var devices = devicesTask.Result;
    if (devices.Any()) //if the device is found
    {
            var deviceInfo = devices.First();
            var serialDeviceTask = SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceInfo.Id);
            serialDeviceTask.Wait();
            var serialDevice = serialDeviceTask.Result;        
            //Set up serial device according to device specifications:
            //This might differ from device to device
            serialDevice.BaudRate = 19600;
            serialDevice.DataBits = 8;
            serialDevice.Parity = SerialParity.None;
      }
}
```